# How to retrieve values from a XML file in iphone?

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse a locally stored XML file in iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412058/how-to-parse-a-locally-stored-xml-file-in-iphone)

I need to retrieve values from an xml file and create button for each value. I am a beginner in iphone application. Please help me..
The xml file is like that...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Dataset>
<RoundTopCategory>
    <CategoryID>83</CategoryID>
    <CategoryName>Lodging</CategoryName>
</RoundTopCategory>
<RoundTopCategory>
    <CategoryID>84</CategoryID>
    <CategoryName>Dining &amp;amp; Grocery</CategoryName>
</RoundTopCategory>
<RoundTopCategory>
    <CategoryID>85</CategoryID>
    <CategoryName>Retail</CategoryName>
</RoundTopCategory>
<RoundTopCategory>
    <CategoryID>86</CategoryID>
    <CategoryName>Art, Culture &amp;amp; Entertainment</CategoryName>
</RoundTopCategory>
<RoundTopCategory>
    <CategoryID>87</CategoryID>
    <CategoryName>Activities</CategoryName>
</RoundTopCategory>
<RoundTopCategory>
    <CategoryID>88</CategoryID>
    <CategoryName>Services</CategoryName>
</RoundTopCategory>
<RoundTopCategory>
    <CategoryID>89</CategoryID>
    <CategoryName>Town, Civic &amp;amp; Emergency</CategoryName>
</RoundTopCategory>
</Dataset>
```

Comment: What if you would make some minimal effort to search this site for your problem before posting a question?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) especially how to ask questions. Please also take the time to find the Search facility to check that questions haven't already been asked and answered

Comment: I searched the site..But those codes causes some errors..

Comment: And the xml is not a local file..

Comment: As you say you are a beginner, perhaps you should take a step back and start with something more simple. Learn the basics and build on that rather than jumping in with something like you are trying to do. Learn how to create buttons using code, then learn how to parse XML. Then put the two together. I think you are trying to run before you can walk.

Comment: I can create buttons using code...But I have problem in parsing xml files..All the samples I got they caused some errors..I need one error free sample that I can understand..And I add the button problem because when I try to add title to buttons using variable it causes problem..Please help..I will be very much thankful to you..

Answer (score 3):

I believe [NSXMLParser](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is what you're looking for. The docs are great for it.

Answer (score 2):

There are many options for parsing XML data in iOS. Josh's pointer to NSXMLParser is a good start; iOS also provides [libxml](http://xmlsoft.org/). There are also quite a few 3rd party libraries meant to make XML in iOS very simple, such as TouchXML. Ray Wenderlich's article, [How to Choose the Best XML Parser for iPhone Project](http://p://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project), provides a solid overview of the various options and advice to help you choose between them.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you need to create NSXMLParser:

```
NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:xmlData];
```

Then you need to create a model to store the retrieve values from the xml file

Parse the xml file using Methods:

```
1.- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName 
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {}
2.- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string { }

3.- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName 
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {}
```

Answer (score 2):

Parsing an XML file is a common task in client server based application. Apple provide NSXMLParser Class for parsing XML file. Study the  [programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/XMLParsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000186i) which will be most helpful. For a quick solution and a tutorial see [this](http://www.xcode-tutorials.com/parsing-xml-files/) link. You can learn XML parsing with step by step explanation from above tutorial.